# Using Obj-c SDK in Swift

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

I'm making an APP these days and it needs to use an Obj-C sdk.
Because I'm new in Obj-C, so I have trouble to using it.

I have make the "Bridge-header.h" and it can be call in swift, but I don't understand how to call it in swift.

here is the example code from SDK's documents

```
    UMComAllFeedsRequest *allFeedRequest = [[UMComAllFeedsRequest alloc] initWithCount:20];

    [allFeedRequest fetchRequestFromServer:^(NSArray *data, BOOL haveNextPage, NSError *error) {
    //Get first page of data
    NSLog(@"feeds is %@",data);
    //Each data element is inside is the UMComFeedobject
    UMComFeed * theFirstFeed = [data firstObject];   
    //If feed more than one page then get other page
    if (haveNextPage == YES){
        [allFeedRequest fetchNextPageFromServer:^(NSArray *data, BOOL haveNextPage, NSError *error) {
            NSLog(@"feeds is %@",data);
        }];
    }
    }];
```

Please help me how to Using it in swift Correctly, Thanks.

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/MixandMatch.html

Comment: Code translation questions are off-topic.

Comment: As noted, code translation is off topic.  Show us what you've tried and how it's not working.

Answer (score 0):

**If you want to add an Objective-C file to your Swift Project**

Add your Objective-C files to your Swift project. Then Xcode will prompt you to add a Bridge-Header. Select ok. In you Bridge-Header, add this:

```
#import "YourFileName.h"
```

Build your project (Cmd+ B); if it successful, you have imported your file correctly. Otherwise you have spelt your file name's wrong.

**If you want to simply write the Objective-C code in Swift**

That question would be considered off-topic. To translate, visit websites such as [ObjectiveC2Swift.com](https://objectivec2swift.com/#/home/main). They help with translation. Also, you can translate on your own, if you are familiar with the syntax of both languages.